# T-SQL date conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following date format `92845` which represent `hhmmss`.

I would like to convert that to a `datetime` in SQL.

I could use something like this:

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF('84936',3,0,'-'),6,0,'-')
```

but it appears T-SQL is not liking the `hour` part.

thank you!

Comment: What is the day, month, year?  Also, I don't see where you are converting to `datetime` in the code you provided.  What is the problem?  What does SQL "not like"?  Is there an error message?

Comment: SQL Server's string manipulation functions are a tad limited and repetitive when you're interested in working from the right-hand end of the string (as here) rather than the left. Do you really have no choice over a) the format this string is arriving in, and b) having to do this reformat in T-SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you wrote the code in the afternoon and now it doesn't work in the morning. If you're going to stuff based on absolute positioning, you need to make sure the string is always the same length. One way to do this is by padding the string with a 0 and then taking the right-most 6 characters. Also, you need `:` not `-` for H/M separators.

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('0' + '84936', 6),3,0,':'),6,0,':');
```

Result:

```
08:49:36
```

Now it can be converted to a datetime:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('0' + '84936', 6),3,0,':'),6,0,':'));
```

Result:

```
1900-01-01 08:49:36.000
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where `92845` is currently stored. If it's in a variable, then something like this will work:

```
declare @t varchar(6) = '92845';
declare @fullt char(6) = RIGHT('000000' + @t,6)

select DATEADD(second,
     SUBSTRING(@fullt,1,2) * 3600 +
     SUBSTRING(@fullt,3,2) * 60 +
     SUBSTRING(@fullt,5,2),0)
```

Result:

```
1900-01-01 09:28:45.000
```

If it's in a column of a result set, then you can do similar manipulations using e.g. subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
declare @t varchar(6) = '134524'
select CASE WHEN len(@t)=5 then convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),CAST(getdate() as date))+' '+'0'+LEFT(@t,1)+':'+SUBSTRING(@t,2,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(@t,4,2))
else convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),CAST(getdate() as date))+' '+LEFT(@t,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(@t,3,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(@t,5,2)) end
```

Comment: Did you try a time like '134524'?

Comment: @Aaron- Thats really a good catch.I edited the script pls check

Comment: Wow, no offense but that's needlessly complicated. Also you cast as Date, why? Do we know the OP is 2008+?

Comment: Yeah compared to ur answer its bit complicated.